# Grafana8.3 webhook way to send test then get "Webhook response status 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

Tags: grafana

when i login the grafana server then found the logs covers some "error level" like:
"msg=Missing receiver logger=alerting.notifier.webhook"
"msg=Missing group labels logger=alerting.notifier.webhook"

Is there anyone had solved this kind of problems or have any ideas, in the grafana7 this way
works.